# how to make a function "list"?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to switch between different labels. I make  a list with buttons and labels. I know that i can add each function I wrote to a list, but I'm looking for a different way in the loop:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x500")

color = ["red", "green", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey"]
lbl = [Label(root, text=f"Label{x}", bg="blue") for x in range(1, 11)]
btn = [Button(root, text=f"Frame{x}")for x in range(1, 11)]

for x in range(10):
    btn[x].pack(side="left", anchor=N, expand=YES, fill=X)
    btn[x].configure(command=lambda : switching(lbl+[x]))
    def switching(lbl):
        lbl[x].place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        lbl[x].configure(text=f"Frame{x}", bg=color[x])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

How can I call the labels, without to create new 9 functions and put them to a list?

Comment: Try: `command=lambda x=x: switching(lbl+[x])`? Can you also state, what you are trying to do with this code?

Comment: I wrote it, in my first sentence. ```I want to switch between different frames```. If I click the first button, the first label should appear... etc. Your suggestion don't work. I want one function, to switch the frames in the loop, with this function.

Comment: @JoeMo So where are the frames in your code? If you are looking for a tabbed widget you should take a look at ttk.NoteBook

Comment: @JacksonPro i mean labels. I edditet in the text. But in the whole things, it would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @CoolCloud commented is correct. you just didn't know how to use it correctly.

You should also keep a variable to keep track of the labels you placed and use `place_forget` to remove them. Also, once you place the label it stays on top of the button so you should lower it.

corrected code

```py
from tkinter import *

def switch(x):
    global previous_index
    lbl_lst[previous_index].place_forget()
    lbl_lst[x].place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    lbl_lst[x].lower()
    previous_index = x

root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x500")

previous_index = 0

color = ["red", "green", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey", "grey"]
lbl_lst = []
btn_lst = []
for index, col in enumerate(color, start=1):
    lbl = Label(root, text=f"Label{index}", bg=col)
    lbl_lst.append(lbl)
    
    btn = Button(root, text=f'Frame{index}')
    btn.config(command=lambda x=index: switch(x-1))
    btn.pack(side="left", anchor=N, expand=YES, fill=X)
    btn_lst.append(btn)

root.mainloop()
```